# How to bind ion-datetime picketFormat?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to set ion-datetime picker format based on my input data related to it.

I am getting date-time format in variable

datePickerFormat="DD MM YYYY hh mm A";

and i am setting  it in html like follow

```
<ion-datetime formControlName='todaydate' pickerFormat={{datePickerFormat}} ></ion-datetime>
```

But i am not getting expected date-time picker format it gives default format

Comment: [pickerFormat]="datePickerFormat" - you should read about angular-bindings

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display like this then just put **displayFormat** in it like this way,

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A" [min]="todayDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="todaydate"></ion-datetime>
```